# Ошибка sh: 1 xvfb-run: not found. Deploy Node Js на сервер

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, nightmare.js

Моё приложение на NodeJs я хочу задеплоить на zeit.co с помощью now.sh.
В моем приложение есть `nightmare.js`, а этот плагин просто так на сервере не заводится для этого нужно установить `xvfb` на сервере под Ubuntu.

Для этого используют команды:

`apt-get -y update`

`apt-get -y upgrade`

`apt-get -y --force-yes install make unzip g++ libssl-dev git xvfb x11-xkb-utils 
xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps clang 
libdbus-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev libnotify-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgconf2-dev 
libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev libxss1 libnss3-dev gcc-
multilib g++-multilib`

и запустить это всё дело нужно так: `xvfb-run node --harmony index.js`

now.sh поддерживает Dockerfile, через который я и устанавливаю эти библиотеки, затем запускаю npm, который устанавливает все пакеты и в итоге запускает `index.js`

Вот сам `Dockerfile`

`FROM ubuntu:14.04
LABEL name "docker"
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y --force-yes install make unzip g++ libssl-dev git xvfb x11-xkb-
utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps clang 
libdbus-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev libnotify-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgconf2-dev 
libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev libxss1 libnss3-dev gcc-
multilib g++-multilib
FROM node:6-onbuild
RUN npm install
RUN npm run start
EXPOSE 80`

A вот скрипт `start` из `package.json`

`"start": "xvfb-run node --harmony index.js"`

Ну и `dependencies`

`"dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.0.3",
    "nightmare": "^2.10.0",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "node-telegram-bot-api": "^0.30.0"
  }`

Когда я это запускаю командой `now --docker` идёт установка всех библиотек, затем npm пакеты и когда выполняется строка `RUN npm run start` консоль выдает `sh: 1 xvfb-run: not found` и в итоге `BUILD ERROR`

Я не понимаю что я делаю не так, пожалуйста подскажите почему возникает эта ошибка, а то я уже отчаялся, неужели придётся переписывать приложение без `nightmare.js`

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что нужно указывать полный путь до исполняемого файла:

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run -a node ./dist/index.js
```

У меня данная команда запускается в systemd без проблем, может и Вам поможет.

Comment: К сожалению это не сработало. Ошибка: `sh: 1 /usr/bin/xvfb-run: not found`

Comment: Странно, что если добавить эти строки:

`RUN export DISPLAY=':99.0'
RUN Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &` всё работает, но в итоге все равно ошибка  `sh: 1 xvfb-run: not found`